# Save result from html2canvas library

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I used html2canvas library to get screenshot of the html content using jvascript. That is what html2canvas library does.

What I tried to do is to get a screenshot of the output from html2canvas library and save it in any image format(say jpeg).
But was not able to achieve it.
Here is what I've tried so far:
**HTML**

```
<svg width="500" height="350">
<circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />
<rect id="blue-rectangle" width="50" height="50" x="25" y="200"     fill="#0099cc"></rect>

<animate 
       xlink:href="#orange-circle"
       attributeName="cx"
       from="50"
       to="450" 
       dur="5s"
       begin="0s"
       repeatCount="2"
       fill="freeze" 
       id="circ-anim"/>

<animate 
       xlink:href="#blue-rectangle"
       attributeName="x" 
       from="50"
       to="425" 
       dur="5s"
       begin="0s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"
       fill="freeze" 
       id="rect-anim"/>

</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
    svg {
    border: 3px solid #eee;
    display: block;
    margin: 1em auto;
    }
    p {
    color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2em 0;
    }
```

**JS(with html2canvas lib)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is wrapping the function by a window.onload

Here are the example

```
 window.onload = function() {
            $("#convert").click(function(){
                html2canvas($('.svgElement')).then(function(canvas) {
                var imgLink = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = imgLink;
                document.body.appendChild(img);
                });
            }); 
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t1fw7pgy/1/

In your code, the function is called before render the element, therefore it will just give you a blank canvas page.